# QT on Cygwin -- IPC Errors

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, cygwin, ipc, ftok

I've downloaded the source for QT 5.6.0 and I'm attempting to compile/install it on a Cygwin installation for Windows.

The Cygwin build already has Qt4 and Qt3 libraries installed.  Trying to upgrade so I can install the latest QtCreator suite.

Here is my Cygwin version via `uname -a`:

```
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 J_Mick-Windoze 2.5.1(0.297/5/3) 2016-04-21 22:14 x86_64 Cygwin
```

When I try to compile QT 5.6.1 via running `./configure -platform cygwin-g++ -prefix $PWD/qtbase -opensource -nomake tests` I get the following error:

```
Running configuration tests (phase 1)...
Done running configuration tests.
Creating qmake...
.In file included from /home/JasonMick/Install_Stuff/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.6.0/QtCore/private/qcore_unix_p.h:1:0,
                 from /home/JasonMick/Install_Stuff/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qglobal.cpp:90:
/home/JasonMick/Install_Stuff/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qcore_unix_p.h: In function ‘key_t qt_safe_ftok(const QByteArray&, int)’:
/home/JasonMick/Install_Stuff/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qcore_unix_p.h:333:12: error: ‘::ftok’ has not been declared
     return ::ftok(filename.constData(), qHash(filename, proj_id));
            ^
make: *** [qglobal.o] Error 1
```

Now clearly there is support for `cygwin` in the `QT` project as grepping inside configure I see the platform:

```
PLATFORM=cygwin-g++
```

...is defined.  Doing some reading I read that `ftok` is a part of the `IPC` group of shared memory functions.  One link regarding a similar error with a different app suggested linking in `-lcygwin`.  I successfully added this to the `L_FLAGS` variable in the configure file, but it's still giving the same error, even when I specify the Cygwin as the platform via the `-platform` flag.

I would appreciate any advice as to how to get rid of this issue -- which I believe is attributable to some sort of missing IPC library error.

Comment: cygwin has QT5.5 already available. Do you really need 5.6 ?

Comment: I can run setup and grab all the qt5.5 related bits... that's my backup plan which I'm currently doing.  But I'm still curious why the build system with the latest source isn't working properly.  

Ideally I'd grab the latest version and build it from the source.  If I can figure out how out how to work around this issue hopefully I can install the latest version.

I often install from source on Cygwin so nothing new there really... don't usually run into this kind of problem.

Comment: Also, finding a solution to this is worth talking about as `qt` definitely is not the only framework to use `ftok` and other `IPC` library calls... this indicates a bunch of programs may not properly compile from source.  Determining the workaround for this particular program has the broader benefit of providing a ready fix when build systems for other application sources fail with `IPC` errors...

Comment: Take cygwin source code package for 5.5 and looks there for the build configuration. I suggest to use cygport for the build to simplify the 5.6 effort

Comment: Okay that's a good idea... I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: I've located the source package for qt5-base here: http://mirror.nexcess.net/cygwin/x86_64/release/mingw64-i686-qt5-base/   ...and am examining it.

Comment: that is not for cygwin build it is for cross-build to mingw64. Use setup to install the proper source package. It will be installed in `/usr/src`

Comment: Ah, I believe the correct src I want is `libQt5Core-devel`.  I see there's a number of patches to that other mingw library... I did some quick searching and read the man page for `patch`, but didn't find a good set of documentation on the syntax/implementation of `*.patch` files. Do you know where I can find documentation regarding the `*.patch` file format?

Comment: `man patch`. Any way install cygport and read the documentation

Comment: Did you see my comment above?  I read `man patch` but it gave little information regarding the syntax/formatting of the `*.patch` file.  I could sort of extract a few details from the text, but for the most part it was solely discussing the `patch` executable's various parameter flags, purpose, known bugs, etc., not the `*.patch` file format.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html#Detailed-Unified